# Make a folder in linux that contains videos linked from other folders

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I store my home photos & videos in directories on linux, sorted by date. Photos and videos are mixed together. How can I create a "virtual folder" that contains a regularly updated (bash & cronjob?) flat index of all videos (*.MOV, *.MP4, *.AVI), recursively scanned, from my photos/video folders?

Example:

```
My photo library:
./2017/2017-06-02 Day at the beach/
./2017/2017-03-15 Dinner with Jan/
./2016/2016-05-12 Fireworks/

Desired video list:
./Videos/filename.mp4
./Videos/CVI285.avi
./Videos/MVI-251.mov
```

Thank you.

Comment: Bash, cronjob and symlinks are certainly a way to go. Are you running into specific issues?

Comment: `find $top_photos_directory} -name '*.mp4' exec ln -s {} $videos_directory +` and repeat for each video type or in a single shot: `find $top_photos_directory} \( -name '*.mp4' -o -name '*.avi' -o -name '*.wmv' \) -exec ln -s -t $videos_directory {} +`

Comment: Hint: you can cover virtually all video types if you test mime types instead of extensions. This is modified code from xenoid's comment: `find "$top_photos_directory" -exec sh -c 'file --mime-type "{}" | grep -q "video/"' \; -exec ln -s -t "$videos_directory" {} +`. Replace `"video/"` with `"audio/"` to test for audio files.